# Cant seem to get withPythonEnv to work in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using an agent setup with multiple versions of Python (3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9) and have installed withPythonEnv plugin to see if it can switch runtimes during builds. The project is found here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pyenv-pipeline-plugin.

When i try to run this in Jenkins running some simple commands:

```
            stage ('Unit Test'){
            steps {
            withPythonEnv('/usr/bin/python3.8') {
                script{
                    sh """
                        pwd
                        env
                        python --version
                        pip install --upgrade pip
                        pip install -r requirements-test.txt
                        python -m pytest foo/tests/ --cov foo --cov-report=xml --junitxml=junit.xml
                    """
                    }
                }
            }
        post {
            always {
                script {
                    junit "junit.xml"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am constantly seeing the build failed. I dont EVER get any additional logging as to why this is occurring. The only message i see is this:

```
ERROR: Error while creating virtualenv: Error: Command '['/home/jenkins/workspace/foo/.pyenv-usr-bin-python3.8/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Does anyone know how to get around this using `withPythonEnv`? Their docs really dont say much more than the examples provided and I've tried a few of those already.

Answer (score -1):

Could you use withEnv and then use PythonPath? Something like: `withEnv('PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3.8')`